# android image upload to quick base db

Tags: java, android

i am developing an android app to upload images to quick base Data Base (https://www.quickbase.com) according to the quick base API , image should upload in base64 format,and its should send via xml formatted post request and no MIME headers and types allowed (http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/whnjs.htm) . every text data going to the data base but image not uploading to the server,here is my code, anyone can give me a help ?

```
String tempXml = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><qdbapi><udata>mydata</udata>"
+ "<ticket>6_bg4at2ksw_bzazsh_b_cmti6qddhsrvgqds7cqmgbt32t6wcdkcse2c8j8ypyb</ticket>"
+ "<apptoken>cwfcy7gdzqrsyncqbi2bn4u4kr</apptoken>"
+ "<field fid='6'>sample data</field><field fid='7'>sample data</field>"
+ "<field fid='8'>sample data</field><field fid='9'>sample data</field>"
+ "<field fid='10'>sample data</field><field fid='12'>sample data</field>"
+ "<field name='message' filename='testImage.jpg'>"
+ testImageName + "</field></qdbapi>";

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String strURL = "https://www.quickbase.com/db/bgtc5pacu?act=API_AddRecord";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strURL);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(tempXml);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 class to get the base64 string from byte array of image.

[base64.java](http://svn.l2jserver.com/branches/L2_GameServer_T2.5/java/com/l2jserver/Base64.java)

Method name: encodeBytes(byte[] source)